# How to get control of my EOS after undelegating?

Tags: staking

I had my EOS staked.  I ran {undelegate} on a portion of it and waited 72 hours.  The amount I unstaked is now showing under "Refund" in the block explorer.

To be clear, when I view the address in the block explorer, I am currently seeing Staked: 0, Unstaked: 0, Refund: XX

How to I free up these EOS to send and/or restake?

Comment: Do you see a general Balance? you should have been given 10 if you were there on Day 1.

Comment: Also check on eosflare, eospark just to see if there's any difference. Some block explorers can give you information in some pretty funky ways.

Comment: So I just ran "unstake" again and waited 3 days and now it's fine.  I dunno

Answer (score 4):

Once the EOS are unstaked you issue the 'refund' command to return them to their liquid state.

```
./cleos push action eosio refund '{"owner": "youraccountname"}' -p youraccountname
```